# Labeling with guide lines the ends of geom_smooth() lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out how to label the ends of the lines from `geom_smooth()` in a ggplot as in the image below (i.e., the "Israel", "United Arab Emirates", etc. labels) with the guide lines (e.g., the thin gray line from "The United States" label to the corresponding plot line) being drawn, perhaps only as necessary. (The lines there are not from `geom_smooth()` but hopefully, the process is the same.) This would be used instead of a standard legend. I've seen answers that address the first part of this, but not the guide lines part. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Example image. I'm trying to label the lines in the same way but in my case, the plot lines would be from geom_smooth().]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way in R to get those nice aligned corner lines, but here's an approach using `ggrepel::geom_text_repel`:

```
library(tidyverse) # using ggplot2 and dplyr
gapminder::gapminder %>% 
  filter(continent == "Americas") %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(year, lifeExp, color = country, label = country)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(data = . %>% filter(year == 2007), size = 2.5, 
                           segment.alpha = 0.4, box.padding = unit(0.01, "cm"),
                           hjust = 0, nudge_x = 20, direction = "y") +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", xlim = c(NA, 2040))
```

[image]